# Demonstrate the use of functions in python (BMI)

Tags: python-3.x, function

I was asked to create a BMI inside a function this is what I have so far the error I receive when trying to run the code is weight is not defined here is my code

```
def bmi(height, weight):

  height = int(input("Input your height in meters: "))
  weight = int(input("Input your weight in kilogram: "))
  result = (weight + height)
  return result
print("Your body mass index is: ", round(weight / (height * height), 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code the height and weight variables exist only within the scope of the bmi function while your last print statement is outside the scope of said function.

A simple fix would be to put the last print before the return like so:

```
def bmi():
  height = int(input("Input your height in meters: "))
  weight = int(input("Input your weight in kilogram: "))
  result = (weight + height)
  print("Your body mass index is: ", round(weight / (height * height), 2))
  return result
```

Since you had two parameters in your bmi function you could restructure your code to retain the origin function definition:

```
def bmi(height, weight):
  result = (weight + height)
  print("Your body mass index is: ", round(weight / (height * height), 2))
  return result

def main():
  height = int(input("Input your height in meters: "))
  weight = int(input("Input your weight in kilogram: "))
  result = bmi(height, weight)
  ...
```